# How determine that a dragging operation has ended in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, drag, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I want to find out if a dragged control has been released outside any target.

One would think that OnDragEnd should be used, but that event doesn't work (they forgot to call the DragEnd procedure in the FMX.Types unit).

As an alternative, I tried OnMouseUp for the dragged control. Doesn't work. Doesn't get triggered when DragMode=dmAutomatic.

As a last resort, I tried to override the MouseUp procedure of the form itself (since all mouse events go through the form before being handed down to the respective control). Surprise: the MouseUp procedure does not get called when the control's DragMode=dmAutomatic.

Amazing how something this very simple is this extremely hard to achieve, but I'm hoping someone might have found a working solution.

Comment: When in drag mode, you'll lose the normal Mouse events since they're caught first by the drag events. As far as getting the drag events to work, hopefully somebody has the answer. It's most likely a bug. Do you have Update 3?

Comment: Yes, have Update 3. I'll report back when I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to override the form's DragLeave method. This method is called for all objects that get dropped outside of a target area.